# Is it common to receive these kinds of crashes? android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, runtimeexception

Is it common to receive these kinds of crashes? This crash has affected one user from about 3000 users. This happens in my first activity in the setContentView. The device is GT-S5830 (Galaxy Ace) in 4.0.4.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.seahorse.android/co.seahorse.android.views.seahorse.SeahorseStartActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x109005b
```

I also receive this crash from only one user. The device is SGH-i747m in 4.3 :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.seahorse.android/co.seahorse.android.views.fragmenttabhost.NewFragmentTabHostActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/tab_indicator_ab_seahorse.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0204e4
```

Obviously the resources are there.

Comment: The user who gets the error, what phone/tablet does he use?

Comment: The device is a GT-S5830 (Galaxy Ace) in 4.0.4. The other is a SGH-i747m in 4.3.